# customer login in as user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I am using rails 3 , devise and cancan for authentication and authorization. I am trying to build a feature where when user call to customer support, support should ask user his/her email and able to log in(without asking for user password). After login support should se only user info. I have a admin feature which will take care of this issue but only problem is that login as admin I will be seeing all the user's info rather than seing specific one. Is there already any feature in  cancan or are there gems to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Devise has a straightforward implementation that should get you started.  I've seen more complex implementations (as I ran into this recently as well) but, again, this should get you going.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Sign-in-as-another-user-if-you-are-an-admin

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Let me give a try.